# when loading Big Size .GLTF MODEL more than 25mb chrome crashed

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I am using GLTF2LOADER and it's unable to load a model size larger than 20MB. Chrome crashed. But it's working fine with only Mozilla. When I use GLTFLOADER.js then its working perfectly fine in all browsers. Not able to track why it's happening. There are many changes between GLTF2LOADER and GLTFloader.js. I am new in this area.
Here is my renderer:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    precision: 'mediump'
});
renderer.setClearColor(0xD8D8D8);
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

var loader = new THREE.GLTF2Loader();
loader.load(url, function(model) {
    var object = model.scene;
    model.animations;
    object.scale.set(20, 20, 20);
    scene.add(object);
    orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
});
```

Comment: I'm not totally clear on the differences betw. GLTF2Loader and GLTFLoader, but I know that if I export from blender using GLTF 2 binary or text export.. I can load them just fine with regular GLTFLoader... Also when you get the chrome crash, what is the error message?
Are you sure it isn't a timeout of some sort due to the load taking too long? Is it a context loss?

Comment: *Any* model > 25mb, or some particular models? If the latter, can you perhaps share one of the problematic models online, ideally from a running repro case?

Comment: What resolution are your textures and how many do you have? Add them all up sum of (`each texture width * height * 5.32`) to see how much memory is needed to load all the textures

Comment: Please use the following version of the loader: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js . The terminology `GLTF2Loader` does not exists anymore. So I guess you use an old version of the loader.

Answer (score 0):

`GLTF2Loader` was the name in use temporarily while glTF 1.0 and 2.0 were supported in separate files.  [It was renamed](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/11961) in r87 to simply `GLTFLoader`.

As @Mugen87 points out in the comments, [that's the version](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js) you should use now for glTF 2.0 files.  Make sure your ThreeJS version and your GLTFLoader version come from the same source tree, as there have been several breaking changes over the past few months.